# How can I send automatic SMS using android apps?

Tags: android, gps, google-play

Suppose I send a SMS (SMS may contain a specific code) from my non android device(i.e. Nokia 1100 or iPhone or any mobile phone) to my android device. Then My developed apps access GPS to find out current location. And my apps send a SMS to my non android device to inform the latitude and longitude where my Android device currently exist.

- I'm very newbie at Android Apps Developing, so I just need to know this kinds of apps is possible or not. And if possible then what should be the basic working procedure.I repeat I didn't ask any code, all I need to know the basic idea of this apps.
- And if this kinds of apps is already exist in Play Store then please let me know.

Comment: Yes it definitely possible. You need a broadcastlistener to listen to incoming messages and when sending message retreive the longitude and latitute.

Comment: Just added my answer below

Answer (score 0):

You need to understand the following:

1. BroadCastReceiver [tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidBroadcastReceiver/article.html)
2. Making apps location aware [tutorial](https://developer.android.com/training/location/index.html)

First you need to have a `BroadCastReceiver` to receive the incoming message and from it retrieve the number of the sender and later send back an sms with the location to the same number.

Below code is not complete code, I have just put some parts of the code

```
  @Override 
  public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
        if (bundle == null) {
              Log.w(tag, "BroadcastReceiver failed, no intent data to process.");
              return; 
        } 
        if (intent.getAction().equals(SMS_RECEIVED)) {
              Log.d(tag, "SMS_RECEIVED");       

            Object[] pdus = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
            final SmsMessage[] messages = new SmsMessage[pdus.length];
            for (int i = 0; i < pdus.length; i++) {
                messages[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdus[i]);
            } 
              String phonenumber= messages[0].getOriginatingAddress();
               sendSMS(phonenumber,locationembeddedmessage);
          }
           .....................
```

The message string `locationembeddedmessage` is the string with the message with location, go over the suggested tutorial in point 2, I have just posted some part of the code.

```
       mLastLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation( 
                mGoogleApiClient); 
        if (mLastLocation != null) { 
            locationembeddedmessage=String.valueOf(mLastLocation.getLatitude())+String.valueOf(mLastLocation.getLongitude());
        }
```

Finally code to send SMS, you need to pass the number and the message to it,

```
private void sendSMS(String phoneNumber, String message)
{
  PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
    new Intent(this, SMS.class), 0);
  SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
  sms.sendTextMessage(phoneNumber, null, message, pi, null);
}
```

There are lot of apps which does this like SMS Location Tracker(Play Store [link](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=sms.location.tracker&hl=en))